# CSS solution to keeping <div> fixed when screensize changes

Tags: css

This code has 
1. textarea on the left
2. a div on the right
Both are next to each other.

The problem: #cxt-machine1 moves/changes or does not stay positioned when screen size changes, when `margin-left:600px;` is changed also.

```
#cxt{position:relative; margin:auto; width:70%; height:300px; border:#CCCCCC 1px solid; background-color:#EEEEEE; margin-bottom:50px;}
    <div id="cxt">
<span>
<div style="position:relative; left:20px; width:50%; height:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">

        <span id="B1" class="styling">B1</span>
        <span id="I1" class="styling">I1</span>
        <span id="U1" class="styling">U1</span>
        <span id="I2" class="styling">I2</span>
        <span id="I3" class="styling">I3 Link</span>
        <span id="B2" class="styling">B2</span>
        <span id="S1" class="styling">S1</span>

</div>
    <div id="PCxt">

    <form method="post" action="">

<textarea cols="75" rows="10" id="Tmat" name="Tmat" style=" position:relative; left:0px"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit">
</form>


    </div>
</span>
<span>
<div> style="position:relative;  width:48%; height:150px; left:448px; top:-258px; max-width:48%; max-height:5px; text-align:center; font-family:arial; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">Cxt-machine Preview</div>
<div id="cxt-machine-1" style="position:fixed;  width:30%; height:250px; margin-left:600px; top:445px; max-width:30%; max-height:250px; overflow: auto; background-color:#ffffff; border:#CCCCCC solid 1px;"></div>
</span>

</div>
```

Looking for solution to keep `#cxt-machine1` fixed in a position irrespective of window size.

---

Sorry...converted everything to table, though I wanted to get the coding tableless, but running out of time, thanks for all your help

Comment: you really shouldn't be nesting divs inside spans like that. Spans are meant for inline. For example, if you wanted to make a word pink, you would use a span. A div is for a logical division, such as "blog-entry" or "main-content"

Answer (score 1):

Give the div, `#cxt` a width in pixels, and you should get the result you want.

Also, give the textarea a width based on percentage or pixels, and don't rely on the `cols` attribute to get the styling you want.

Comment: #cxt-machine1 moves away from #PCxt when screen size decreases and closer when screen size increases.

Comment: That's probably because the div before it has a percentage width. Also you have div's inside a span. You shouldn't do that. Could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry...converted everything to table, though I wanted to get the coding tableless, but running out of time, thanks for your help